# Principle of Energy Dispersive x-ray Spectroscopy

Tags: spectroscopy, x-rays, dispersion

I have a question about the EDS

I don't understand how the detector can differentiate the Energy of incident x-ray **simultaneously**.

In my thought, the emitted x-ray from the sample have different energies and

It reaches the detector simultaneously in general.

So the current made by that x-ray photon bunches is gathered

It's impossible to differentiate the energy of each x-ray photon.

Am I wrong?

But the data of EDS shows the histogram of dispersive energy of emitted x-ray.

Plz let me know what I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand how the detector can differentiate the Energy of incident x-ray **simultaneously**.

The simple answer is that the detector cannot.

Ideally the energy of a single photon is converted into a voltage pulse of size related to the energy of the photon.
An incoming photon produces electron-hole pairs and the resulting current pulse is integrated by a fet amplifier whose charge output is then “shaped” into a voltage pulse.

The flux rate of incoming photons is adjusted so that the dead time of the detector and peak pile up have a small effect on the accuracy of the output of the detector.
Furthermore sophisticated signal processing of the output voltage pulses can reduce the errors due to these effects.

[This paper](https://cime.epfl.ch/webdav/site/cime2/shared/Files/Teaching/EDX/Introduction%20to%20EDS.pdf) gives much more information about the whole process.